# Is it safe to put a linked worktree under a .gitignore'd dir of the main worktree?

Tags: git, git-worktree

Is it safe to put a linked git worktree under a .gitignored subdir of the main git worktree?

E.g. in the root of the main worktree I'd do

```
mkdir tmp
echo 'tmp/**' >> .gitignore
git worktree add -b tmp-branch-01 tmp/tmp-branch-01
```

The webpage at https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/06/26/parallelize-development-git-worktrees/ says a linked worktree "should be somewhere outside of your main repository directory", but doesn't say why.  Will putting it inside the main worktree break any invariants git expects, if it's under a .gitignored dir?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only real risk here is yourself, or scripts you might run that do these kinds of things: you might forget you have a worktree in `tmp` and `rm -rf tmp` or `git clean -dfx`.

You might also accidentally edit your `.gitignore` and forget that it's important to continue ignoring `tmp/tmp-branch-01`, or something.

These sorts of scenarios aside, there's no real problem with putting the added work-tree inside the main work-tree.  I prefer to put them *next to* the main work-tree, though.